# Issue regarding firewalld

Tags: firewalld

I want to automatically add my `eth0` to be part of internal zone in `firewalld`.

How to achieve this during provisioning?

Answer (score 2):

You should edit your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` then append the following line at the bottom of your file:

```
zone=your_internal_zone
```

> [How to set or change a zone for a connection](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Firewalld?rd=FirewallD#How_to_set_or_change_a_zone_for_a_connection)
>
> The zone is stored into the ifcfg of the connection with the `ZONE= option`. If the option is missing or empty, the default zone set in firewalld is used.
>
> If the connection is controlled by NetworkManager, you can also use `nm-connection-editor` to change the zone.

Then restart the services:

```
sudo systemctl restart network.service
sudo systemctl restart firewalld.service
```

Comment: Thanks......GAD3R....this seems working for me also got cleared my doubt.